# Do we have to compile Mesos on each and every node?

Tags: mesos, ubuntu-18.04

I am building a Mesos cluster on 3 three masters and 2 slaves.  Each VM has at least 4 vCPUs and 2Gb of memory.  In the past, I compiled Mesos on each one of the servers which took a ridiculous amount of time to complete.  Even when I used this command to build:

```
make -j 4 V=0
```

My question is, am I doing it wrong?  The [building instructions](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/building/) say nothing about multiple node clusters.  I don't want to install from the distribution binaries because I want the latest.

Comment: I even bumped all the Vms to have 4Gb of memory each and it still takes forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use `docker`.

Next are 2 docker images from `mesosphere` which afford most latest docker images for master & slave.

https://hub.docker.com/r/mesosphere/mesos-master/tags/

https://hub.docker.com/r/mesosphere/mesos-slave/tags/

With this, you can just pull images from dockerhub, and directly run container for mesos master & mesos slave without compile sourcecode, FYI.